# Time it takes for light to travel from horizon

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation

If a pair production happened at the horizon thereby producing Hawking radiation. The outgoing radiation will travel from the horizon to some external radial distance $r$. I wanted to know how to calculate the time it takes for it to travel given some distance or the distance it takes given the time.

I know based on GR, there are effects that you need to consider like gravitational time dilation and an infalling particle seems to slow down as it approaches the horizon, etc. However, applying the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates on the Schwarzschild metric and looking at the Finkelstein diagram, it seems to me that there should be no problem calculating the time it takes light to travel from the horizon to some external radial distance in these coordinates since light is just a 45 degree line [1].

If we look at the outgoing Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates p. 243 in [1],

$$u=t-r_* \;, \qquad dr^2_* = \Bigg(1-\frac{2GM}{r} \Bigg)^{-2} dr^2$$

$$dt = du + dr_* = du + \Bigg(1-\frac{2GM}{r} \Bigg)^{-1} dr$$

Substituting this to the Schwarzschild metric we get,

$$ds^2 = - \Bigg(1-\frac{2GM}{r} \Bigg) du^2 - 2dudr + r^2 d\Omega^2.$$

For a null geodesic ($ds^2 = 0$) one of the solutions is $du=0$ so that we have,

$$dt = \Bigg(1-\frac{2GM}{r} \Bigg)^{-1} dr$$

but when you integrate this from $r_H = 2GM$ to some radial distance $r_0$, this is divergent in the lower limit which means the time is also divergent. How does this reconcile with the Finkelstein diagram and the idea that it takes a finite time for a photon emitted ***just*** at the horizon to travel to some radial distance $r_0$?

[1] Chapter 6 Black Holes. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gr/gr.pdf

Comment: You need to integrate from some distance outside the horizon. It takes only a second to get from the Planck length distance to substantially far away. For shorter distances see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Planckian_problem

Comment: @safesphere Very nice entry from wiki. The question is how much distance outside the horizon? Should it be comparable to some scale, say the Planck time (which goes to the problem stated in the wiki) or whatever so that the semiclassical description is justified?

Comment: @safesphere In the paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506121) referenced in the wiki, it basically quantifies the distance from the horizon which remedies this trans-Planckian problem using a truncation method. They called this distance $x$ the edge of the trans-Planckian zone. On p. 13, the corresponding quantities including the distance $x$ is stated as a function of this modified momentum function $g(p)$. It says that for $p>1$, $x = 4M\omega/g(p) \sim O(1)$. What does this $O(1)$ mean? Order 1 with respect to what?

Comment: Each distance provides a contribution to the total intensity, but your question is time and time is easily calculated for each distance.